# discord py adding role via DM

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to have this bot reply via DM's, but the only issue is that it keeps running into
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`

the current code I have:

```
@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    server = bot.get_guild({serveridhere})
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="verified")
    member = server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)
    if int(arg2) in verificationcodes:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.author.send('Success! The verified role has been added to your account!')
    else:
        print("Verification code is INVALID!")
```

Comment: Make sure you have guild members intent on I guess discord.py v1.5 enforced it you may read the info [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html). If they're enabled try logging member as `print(member)`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed this by adding intents